# How to get token from server BrainTree

Tags: java, android, .net, httpclient, braintree

How do I get the token from my server? I went the tedious process of simply getting the token to appear on my server but now I don't know how to pull it down and use it in my Android app. This is the method that Braintree suggested and it had a boat load of errors when I copied and pasted it. I managed to get past them but I had to implement a few methods that I don't think are right.

All I need to be able to do is get the client token and use as a variable in my app. Someone please help. P.S. I'm really new at Android dev.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.BraintreePaymentActivity;

import org.apache.http.Header;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private int REQUEST_CODE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public void fetchClientToken() {
        client.get("http://clomes.com/clomes/braintree/customer/gettoken", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            public String clientToken;

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String clientToken) {
                this.clientToken = clientToken;
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you'll want to move your `clientToken` field to be a field of your `Activity` and not the `TextHttpResponseHandler`. Next you'll need to call the `fetchClientToken` method at some point or you will never make the network request for the client token. If the request is successful you should be able to use the client token then.

Comment: @alex have you get the solutons for that or not? i am getting same problem. when i try to call from my  server we get log in Onfailure method